# Nested Inner Component Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a component ModelManagerExample that has multiple inner components Disclosure Component and ContentComponent.I am trying to write the test for this component using shallow rendering ,but since my inner components are not exported,I am not able to use those components in my test component.

```
 class DisclosureComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

   }

  componentDidMount() {
   // code
    }
 render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    const disclosureManager = this.context;
   return (
     <ContentContainer fill>
       <DisclosureManagerHeaderAdapter
        title="Add New User"
        collapsibleMenuView={(null
        )}
    />


     </ContentContainer>
  );
}
 }
  DisclosureComponent.contextType = DisclosureManagerContext;
  DisclosureComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  addNewUser: PropTypes.func,
};
 DisclosureComponent.defaultProps = {
  name: 'Disclosure Component',
};


class ContentComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.renderButton = this.renderButton.bind(this);
}

 render() {
    return (
  );
}
}
 ContentComponent.contextType = DisclosureManagerContext;
 ContentComponent.propTypes = {
   disclosureType: PropTypes.string,
   addNewUser: PropTypes.func,
};

const propTypes = {
   addNewUser: PropTypes.func,
 };
  const ModalManagerExample = props => (


    <ContentComponent disclosureType="modal" addNewUser={props.addNewUser} />


 );
ModalManagerExample.propTypes = propTypes;
export default ModalManagerExample;
```

My test component:Since ContentComponent is not exported so it is not able to recognise this component.How can i write the jest for this as the inner components are not exported

```
 describe('ModalManagerExample', () => {
   it('Should Render Component Correctly', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<ModalManagerExample addNewTenant={this.addNewTenant} />);
   expect(wrapper.find(ContentComponent)).toHaveLength(1);

  });
});
```

Comment: you would have to utilize full rendering: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md

Comment: How would i still use "ContentComponent" if i use mount rendering

Comment: I don't understand. Is `ContentComponent` rendered within `ModelManagerComponent`? If so, you can target it with .find() method. If you don't export `ContentComponent` you can find it by other properties like className, id, tag, or even component display name `wrapper.find('ContentComponent')` - https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html

Comment: This is what I have tried from the link you provided me describe('ModalManagerExample', () => {
  const addNewTenant = jest.fn();
  it('Should Render Component Correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ModalManagerExample addNewTenant={addNewTenant} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('ContentComponent')).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});

Comment: I am able to get the ContentComponent but how can i access the DisclosureComponent which is called by ContentComponent like I want to say expect(wrapper.find(ContentComponent)).toHaveLength(1);expect(wrapper.find(DisclosureComponent)).toHaveLength(1); but it says received length 0 for DisclosureComponent when i run the tests

Comment: @Wiktor Bednarz it works now with the link you provoded.Thanks :)

Comment: if the `DisclousureComponent` is rendered within `ModelManagerComponent`, then you find it the same way - `wrapper.find(`DisclousureComponent`)`. But in the code you submitted it's not clear what is rendered by `ModelManagerComponent`. If all the names are correct in your test suite, then it looks like `ModelManagerComponent` doesn't render the `DiscousureComponent` as you expected.

Comment: Can you show in the question how these components are related? There's no <DisclosureComponent> in the code you provided. You can do things like `find('ContentComponent')` but this should be the last resort and may fail if component `displayName` differs for one reason or another. *since my inner components are not exported* - is there a reason why it's so? This hurts testability a lot. Could be improved by simply adding `export` to components. Also, there are good reasons why "one file per component" practice is forced in React community, notably this allows to reuse and test them separately.